# I2C Isolation using Switch

Tags: i2c

In my design I have a controller which is interfaced to the processor (or SoC) using I2C. The processor has internal pull ups for I2C lines so I don't need to put external pull ups.
The voltage rail for controller is on regardless of the state of processor (on or off).
The voltage rail for the processor is on when the system is on.

The issue is when the system is off the I2C lines of controller are in undefined state and it consumes more power. This issue is not observed when the system is on and the I2C lines are in a valid state.

If I put pull ups outside powered by an always on rail then I see a leakage on the pull up resistors to the processor I2C pins - possibly leakage through clamping diodes for the processor pins.
How can I isolate the I2C lines of processor and controller without causing leakage and undefined state?

I2C lines for controller and processor work at 1.8 V.

Comment: WHen you say the processor is off, do you mean its power supply is shut off, or just that you put it in a low-power or sleep state?

Comment: Use an I2C isolator, e.g. http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt403/slyt403.pdf I did a web search for "i2c isolator", and found several devices.

Comment: Yes, the processor's supply is off.

Comment: How much isolation you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

(I can't comment yet - not enough points, so this is more of a comment than an answer.)
Please clarify the power supply conditions for the SoC and the controller when both are on and when "the system is off."
- When "on," are they both operating at the same voltage (what voltages)?
- And when the system is "off", you mean the SoC is off and the controller is on?  From your comment that the I2C lines are in an undefined state, that appears to be the case (the SoC supply is off, so the I2C lines are no longer pulled up).

The leakage you are seeing is from the controller supply to the SoC I2C pins' ESD diodes to the SoC supply.  If you check, the SoC supply is probably not at ground but is pulled up a little by the external pullups you added.

By "it consumes more power," are you referring only to the current in the pullup resistors or also to supply current of the controller IC?  CMOS input logic needs to be driven at a supply or ground level to avoid drawing current (crowbar current or shoot-through current) that occurs when the input is somewhere between the supply and ground voltages.

Here's an option that might avoid an isolator:

Add external pull *down* resistors on the I2C lines to ground.  Make these weak, on the order of 100kohm.  If the SoC is not powered, then this will be sufficient to ensure the lines are pulled to ground and the leakage in the controller input logic will be avoided.  And when the SoC is on, there will be additional leakage current through these, e.g. 3.3V/100k x 2 = 66uA.  If that is negligible in your power budget then this might be a decent solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific point of importance here: the very nature of I<sup>2</sup>C as a bus (and perhaps the *only* bus) specifically designed to allow zero leakage with one or more chips on the bus powered off. I<sup>2</sup>C accomplishes this by being an **open collector** bus and **open collector** means that there is **nothing** pulling the data lines high inside a compliant IC. But alas, a generic digital IO pin in a microcontroller or wherever, which can be driven high or low, cannot satisfy this condition.

A push-pull digital pin has a P channel high side driver and protection structures connected to the power supply rail, which means that such a pin will always leak current towards the power supply rail if the voltage of that rail is less than the voltage at the pin, minus a diode's forward voltage. Such pins have a V<sub>I,MAX</sub> condition of V<sub>CC</sub>+0.6 volts or such stated in the datasheet. Can you check if the datasheet states such a condition for the pins? If it does, in reverse it means that the minimum for V<sub>CC</sub> in such an IC is the I<sup>2</sup>C bus voltage minus 0.6 volts.

As a consequence, microcontroller can have an I2C -style port (which is not I<sup>2</sup>C logo certified), or use generic I/O pins to communicate with I<sup>2</sup>C devices, but it is only logically compatible with I<sup>2</sup>C when the microcontroller is powered up. I<sup>2</sup>C compliant devices must use specific IO pads for the I<sup>2</sup>C signals and they cannot have the high side driver, and I suspect pull-ups of any kind would be at least problematic.

If you want to take advantage of I<sup>2</sup>C's zero leakage powerdown properties, you must either use only specific I<sup>2</sup>C ports or convert a generic IO pin to an open collector (or open drain) -style arrangement somehow, cutting all current paths to the high side. It would seem to me that if you would have a signal of sufficiently higher voltage than your I<sup>2</sup>C bus voltage of 1.8 volts (3 volts or more), you could use NFETs (n-channel, enhancement-type mosfet, the 'normal' kind) to "cut" the SCL and SDL lines when the SoC has no power. You would connect the NFETs with source towards the SoC, drain towards the bus and gate to a 3 volt enable signal. Choose an NFET with a sufficiently low threshold voltage so that the channel is surely conducting when the signal is at 1.8 volts. So at most 1.2 volts if your enable signal is 3 volts.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXlSeL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

A) an I2C isolator should do the trick.  I have had good luck with http://www.analog.com/en/interface-isolation/digital-isolators/adum1250/products/product.html

B) Internal pullups on processors tend to be weak pullups, and the resistance may be too high for reliable i2c function.  You might consider external pullups of the right size.

Comment: I had done a search for these kinda devices but they all operate at high voltage levels 3.0 or 3.3. My I2C is working at 1.8 level.

Comment: I think you may have to use voltage translator to 3.3V and then isolator to achieve this. since you can't use optocoupler  because I2c is bidirectional.

Comment: Nope, @AKR, the ICC isolators need pullups onot both sides to the right value, but handle the conversion IIRC

Comment: @ScottSeidman Agree with you but since OP is looking for 1.8V operation and most of the available isolators work at minimum of 3.0V.