# I2C bit banging

Tags: i2c

I have to implement I2C using bit banging as the controller doesnot supports the I2C drivers. So in order to generate SCL clock, there should be delays so as to generate the Clock high and low periods. Which method is best to generate the delay, A) using nops/for loops, or B) delays generated by using a general purpose timer?

Answer (score 7):

It really depends on whether you need to be doing something else at the same time, and also the speed of your processor. If you can completely block your application (main loop) while the I²C runs, then using software delays is much easier. But with a fast processor, you are wasting hundreds of instructions that could be used for something else.

However if you need to handle other I/O and/or do calculations in the main loop at the same time, then interrupts would be the way to go.  But you have be able to execute enough instructions between bits to make this worthwhile, since interrupts, by their nature, add some additional overhead.  With either approach, you would need to implement some sort of state machine to keep track of what to do next.

An I²C interface typically runs at 100 kHz or 400 kHz.   So this would mean an interrupt every 10 µs or 2.5 µs, respectively. For a reasonably fast processor, say a PIC32 running at 80 MHz, this represents either 800 or 200 one-cycle instructions between bits, so no problem.

But for a processor running at 8 MHz and I²C running at 400 kHz, there are only 20 instructions per bit so using interrupts may not be doable, since you have to service the interrupt (saving registers and acknowledging the interrupt flag), generate the clock pulse (SCL), obtain the data bit to be sent and send it (SDA) 1/2 bit after the clock edge, update a bit counter and maybe state, restore registers and return.  Probably not gonna happen in 20 instructions, even in assembly language.

The reason for the 1/2 bit timing, is that you are generating both the clock (SCL) and data (SDA) pulses.  The clock falls in the middle of the data bit, so the slave can use the edge to clock data into its register (see below).

[image]

So with slower processors, you are probably going to need to use software delays.  You could create a function (or macro) to delay 1/2 bit time to generate both the SCL and SDA pulses, but that doesn't allow for the overhead of fetching the next bit and updating the bit counter.  Adding that overhead would mean your bus would run a little slower than 400 kHz (but should work okay).  By including the overhead into your timing calculation (therefore delaying just a less than 1/2 bit time to make the overall timing come out okay), you would be able to run at full speed.  This will require careful counting of machine cycles to maximize the speed.

Answer (score 1):

Totally dependent on your circuit. Keep in mind that I2C devices tend to have a maximum speed, and a minimum timing between clock pulses, **but tend to be completely liberal at lower speeds**. You can bit bang I2C at very low speeds if you want or need. I've used general port expanders at speeds as low as 25 kHz and the ICs wouldn't have a single issue with it.

Your delays between clocking SCL high and low just needs to be slow enough to meet the minimum timing, which can be done with a few NOPs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one more point of view for you to consider. First you should consider *which problem you need to solve:* is it generic I2C connectivity **or** just interfacing to one or two specific chips.

If you need to make a generic I2C host which can communicate with any I2C chip, you need to implement the delays correctly, including clock stretching. But if you just need to communicate with a specific IC, check that IC's datasheet for timing requirements and do some testing also. There's probably no circuitry inside an IC specifically designed to *require* any certain timing, the timing requirements of the bus come from needing to satisfy conditions for pull-up currents, capacitances, lengths of the wiring, maximum fan-outs, this and that. The chip itself probably just requires recognizable SDA, SCL edges and levels and can function at the limits of the process, which means megaherts' (unless that chip also is using software to sample the lines and emulate I2C).

If your I2C bus runs only in your PCB between just a couple of chips, do the same consideration for pull-up resistors. Your electrical requirements for the bus may be considerably easier than requirements for a generic I2C bus. For example, you can most likely use normal push-pull driving of the SDA and SCL pins when you are driving the bus instead of relying on the pull-up resistor and maybe even overwrite ACKs.

Note that if you are using microcontroller pins for implementing I2C, it's *very difficult* to do it with full accordance to the spec *anyway*, because I2C specification requires that the pins are plain open collectors - there must not be any leakage whatsoever on the high side, to allow any chips on the bus to be powered up or down independently. **No generic microcontroller pins can satisfy this**, since they invariably have high side protection structures. Again, this is not a problem if you have total control of the bus so that you are the only master and thus you can control powering of the bus lines, e.g. you can pull high to your microcontroller's digital supply voltage. But it *is* a problem if you are designing a slave IC which needs to be powered off while the rest of the system is powered on. If you need to respect this aspect of I2C bus, you need external circuitry.

So in summa summarum, my point of view is that you probably should not solve a larger problem than what you need to solve - you might very well get away with just making the bus work with the specific chip that you need to support. But do *that* as well as you can, with sufficient margins for error. And if it's not too costly, keep also *some* aspects of expandablity, upgradability and design reuse in mind.

See also: [I2C Isolation using Switch](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/130860/i2c-isolation-using-switch/150709#150709)

Answer (score 0):

i will voice an opinion that is different from the previous answers.

generating delays using *"timing loops"* (with NOPs and FOR or DO loops) is simple and reliable, **but not re-entrant**.  i.e. it's what you can do if you have no other tasks bothering the micro-controller at the time of the I²C communication.  so this cannot be used in an active multi-threaded context.

if your bit-banging I²C is being done when *other* tasks must also be tended to, then you must use the timer and write re-entrant code to do this.  you must cycle through each task's thread in a rapid and efficient manner.  each thread must quickly check if its task needs attention or not and get out quick if not.

and if any thread's task **does** need attention, you must give it the attention it needs and get out quick.  if the attention any particular task needs is not a quick action, then that thread must somehow be bumped down in priority so the I²C bit-banger is not messed up.

in addition, because you are not certain how much MIPS or time is used by the other threads, you must reduce the clock rate of the I²C SCL line so that the jitter that might result from the actions of the other threads is small compared to the clock period.

i am working on a  ADI SHArC application (which **does** have a built-in I²C or "TWI" but i am not using it) and i converted re-entrant bit-banging with simpler non-re-entrant bit banging using timing loops.  it reduced the code size greatly and since the I²C communications was being done solely to initialize control registers of peripheral chips upon reset, there were no active interrupts or competing threads.  so re-entrant code simply was not necessary.

Comment: I2C is completely asynchronous so it really doesn't matter how much jitter you introduce. One clock period could be 10us and the next 5ms and everything will still work fine, as long as you obey the minimum times. The exception is that some slave devices will reset if a clock period is too long, as a safety measure. But these timeouts are, as far as I know, in the 10s and 100s of ms. It is reasonably safe to run the bit-banging with timing loops while still servicing interrupts.

Comment: *"It is reasonably safe to run the bit-banging with timing loops while still servicing interrupts."* -- you're probably right, but it still makes me nervous.

Comment: This answer appears to confuse reentrancy and thread safety (which are related but not identical) and, in turn, multi-threading and cooperative multitasking as performed on simple microcontrollers.

Answer (score -1):

Busy waiting (NOPs) is usually the worst option but the easiest to implement.

Comment: But timer option is difficult to implement. Am I correct?

Comment: More difficult than the busy waiting option, yes. Still, it can be done. Consider using a state machine approach.

Comment: L: can i have some reference code for the same, using timer .

Comment: Something like http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/i2c-state-machine? Doesnt necessarily require a timer although in a real application you'd use one. Just make sure your timer executes the state machine.

Comment: @xyz101 You haven't even specified which architecture you're using.

Comment: architecture means?

Comment: @xyz101  "*architecture means?*"  and "\[from [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/181571/spi-chip-select-queries#comment373913_181571)] *I didnt get you. are you not able to understand my query?*"  You don't possess enough basic knowledge to understand responses that you receive on EE.SE .

Comment: A little more detail on _why_ would make this a good answer and remove it from the low quality queue..

Comment: not down-arrowing, Tom, but i don't agree with your "usually the worst option" assessment.  i think usually it's the best option because usually the I2C communication is done upon the initialization period of an embedded device.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson   Can't agree with the last sentence.  There are quite a few devices where I2C communication takes place multiple times a second all the time, not just at the initialization.  (I have designed devices like that around MSP430 and PIC.)

Comment: @NickAlexeev, certainly you have done more than me.  my experience is simply to reset and initialize codecs as the system starts up.  i know that I²C is done with sensors and the like that are reporting data all the time.  in that case, the I²C bit-banger has to be re-entrant.  and you must make sure the other threads are equally-well re-entrant.

Comment: Well in that case I don't hope that you have to read any temperature or humidity sensors ...

Comment: can you elaborate @TomL.?

Comment: A task which has to be performed continuously. Switching between different I2C busses (pca9547). IO Expanders (pca 9535)  .. all tasks which need to be performed continuously.